# Using SUM function with subqueries Typeorm

Tags: mysql, nestjs, typeorm

I want to build these query with queryBuilder i have tried it but giving error
MYSQL QUERY -

```
select sum(total), count(invoiceId) 
  from(
    select sum(price) as 'total', invoiceId from items
      group by items.invoiceId
  )
as ie;
```

I have written these in typeorm but not working

```
const data = await this.itemsRepo
  .createQueryBuilder('items')
  .select('sum(price)', 'total')
  .groupBy('invoiceId')
  .getQuery();
    
return await this.itemsRepo
  .createQueryBuilder()
  .select('COUNT(ie.total)', 't')
  .from(`${data}`, 'ie')
  .getRawMany();
```

showing these error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '` FROM `items` `items` GROUP BY invoiceId` `ie`' at line 1
```

& genrated query by typeorm is

SELECT sum(price) AS `total` FROM `items` `items` GROUP BY invoiceId

items entity

```
@Entity()
export class Items {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;
  @Column()
  item: string;
  @Column()
  hsn: number;
  @Column()
  qty: number;
  @Column()
  material: number;
  @Column()
  price: number;
  @Column()
  invoiceId: number;
  @ManyToOne(() => Invoices, (invoice) => invoice.items)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'invoiceId' })
  invoice: Invoices;
}
```

Invoice Entity

```
@Entity()
export class Invoices {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;
  @Column()
  challanNo: string;
  @Column()
  transportaion: number;
  @Column()
  clientId: number;
  @ManyToOne(() => Client, (client) => client.invoices)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'clientId' })
  client: Client;
  @OneToMany(() => Items, (item) => item.invoice)
  items: Array<Items>;
  @CreateDateColumn({
    type: 'timestamp',
    default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)',
  })
  created_at: Date;
}
```

Comment: Is `count(invoice)` supposed to be `count(invoiceId)`?

Comment: yes it is sorry i will update it

Comment: Replace `this. itemsRepo` with `getConnection()` or `getManager()` and it should work.